# How to upload image and attach document using angular editor

Tags: angular, editor

I installed angular editor package and the angular editor is working , but I'm unable to upload word document,presentation and image

I installed angular editor from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kolkov/angular-editor

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularEditorConfig } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';
import {BlogService} from 'src/app/service/blog.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css']
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {

  editorConfig: AngularEditorConfig = {
    editable: true,
    spellcheck: true,
    height: '25rem',
    minHeight: '5rem',
    placeholder: 'Enter text here...',
    translate: 'no',
   uploadUrl: '/home/web/Pictures', // if needed
    customClasses: [ // optional
      {
        name: "quote",
        class: "quote",
      },
      {
        name: 'redText',
        class: 'redText'
      },
      {
        name: "titleText",
        class: "titleText",
        tag: "h1",
      },
    ]
  };

  constructor(private blogservice: BlogService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  Save(blogForm: any) {

    if (blogForm.valid === true) {
      blogForm = blogForm.value;
      this.blogservice.Save(blogForm).subscribe(response => {console.log(response);
        });
      window.alert('Blog published successfully');


     }

   }

}
```

Presently I'm able to add styles to the content in the editor , but expect to add image and other docs

Answer (score 5):

```
uploadUrl: '/home/web/Pictures', // if needed
```

This is not actually url where your images get uploaded, but url of backend service that handles uploading and return the location of image after uploading is done.

In frontend/component:

```
uploadUrl: 'localhost:8080/server/page/upload-image',
```

In Backend, in file where ever `upload-image` is being routed:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
   //Here you do the uploading. The way you do is up to you. 


   //Once you have done with image uploading, you have to return path to image. I was using google cloud service and there I am dealing with absolute paths, so I don't know if relative path is going to work.

   res.status(200).send({
       "status":true, 
       "originalName":'demoImage.jpg', 
       "generatedName":'demoImage.jpg', 
       "msg":"Image upload successful", 
       "imageUrl":`https://storage.googleapis.com/article-images/demoImage.jpg`
   })

})
```

Then the `imageUrl` you are returning from backend, gets wrapped with `<img></img>` tags and pasted into editor.